# What iPhone model is shown in Apple's Recycling video?

Tags: iphone

In Apple's most recent event, they highlighted their environmentally-friendly products. One of their videos sported a robot named Liam, who would disassemble iPhones once they were in need of recycling.

However, in the video I couldn't place the iPhone shown on the disassembly line. I've included an image below. Can somebody identify it? Or is it not an iPhone in the current lineup, something different or...dare I say...new?

Looks like it has a flush camera lens, which is something the newer models don't have. That's what's confusing me.

Link to the video is [right here](http://www.apple.com/recycling/), at the bottom of the page.

[image: iPhone on disassembly line]

Comment: Could you please add the link to the video.

Comment: Of course. One moment...

Comment: There we go. Video's at the bottom of the page.

Comment: This video is amazing. Anyway, I think the iPhone is an iPhone 6 or just a fake one. For sure the video is enormously edited and this I guess is the explanation at the thing that confused you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Judging by the guts of it, the size, and the finish, I am going to say that this is an

## iPhone 6

It's too big and rounded to be a 5/5S series or earlier.  Assuming that it's not the iPhone 7 (which hasn't even hit the prototype phase), we can narrow it down to a iPhone 6 or 6S.  There is one slight difference between the two:

[image: iPhone 6/6S difference]

In our little video we see that it has only the iPhone name on it:

[image: iPhone 6 with non-S identification]

So, that's why I say it's an

## iPhone 6

Comment: Apple is secretly telling all of us to recycle our Sixes and get the S model.

Comment: Either that, or the video was made before the iPhone 6S was released, so they didn't want to give away its presence.